# include mongoose models into single js which is include in node.js file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, node.js-connect

I am creating node app using mongo mongoose .I have models separate file where all data modules are created and i want to be configured all data models into one js files which we have to include in node.js file(server.js)
Here i have user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

module.exports = function() {
    var users = new Schema({
        name     : String
      , body      : String
      , date      : Date
    });
    mongoose.model("users", users);
};
```

books.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; 

module.exports = function() {
    var books = new Schema({
        title     : String

    });
    mongoose.model("books", books);
};
```

now i want to be include these books.js and user.js file into one single js file 
so i created one

model.js

```
var models = ['users.js','books.js'];

module.exports.initialize = function() {
   var l = models.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        require(models[i])();
    }

};
```

and i include this model.js file in server.js file

```
require('./models/model.js').initialize();
```

When i was trying to run this ,i got error that " cannot find model books.js and user.js"

i think the error is in model.js So can you please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `models.js` file to something like this:

```
var users = require('./users');
var books = require('./books');

module.exports.initialize = function () {
    return {
        users: users(),
        books: books()
    };
}
```

Make sure your `require()`s are accessing the correct file paths.